# Setting up Cron and CiviMail

Tags: wordpress, civimail, cron

CiviCRM is telling me I need to set up Cron jobs and CiviMail, but I've looked at the documentation and it's all Greek to me. How can I get help with setting these up?

I'm using Wordpress with Bluehost VPS hosting.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/difficulty-setting-up-civimail-on-bluehost?rq=1 may have some hints (including 'do not use bluehost')

Comment: also this which came in very recently so perhaps your overlaps this one? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/civimail-is-not-sending-scheduled-mailings-could-it-be-cronjob-syntax-or-blueho